# can a spring rest service call its own rest template method postForEntity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am developing a restful application where my application is posting data through the rest template. The URI for post is /employee. A rest template is calling this uri and posting data into the database. Is there a way for posting the data through the /employee from postman and making it access the rest template?

Comment: Yes. Thats what postman is for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do we have any examples available on that?

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/